# Why s:select not working in s:iterator tag?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I have an issue with a select in an iterator. Whenever I use the `index` value of my iterator `status` in the name property of the select, the form isn't submitting properly.

In my code I use a `first iterator` to iterate through a list of days and a `second iterator` to  iterate through my records to display and edit their data.

**page.jsp:**

```
<s:iterator value="daysOfWeek" var="jour" status="stat">
    <div class="gu desk-s1 desk-w2" id="plage${stat.index}">
        <s:text name="%{#jour}"/>
        <s:submit type="button" action="addPlage/%{#stat.index}">+</s:submit>
        <s:iterator value="plageRecords" var="plage" status="innserStat">
            <s:if test="%{#plage.jour == #stat.index}">
                <s:include value="plage/plage_cell.jsp"/>
            </s:if>
        </s:iterator>
    </div>
</s:iterator>
```

**page_cell.jsp:**

```
<div class="g rev-width rev-top-m1">
    <div class="gu desk-w6">
        <label><s:text name="admin.plage.label.endHour" /></label>
        <s:fielderror class="fieldError"
                      fieldName="plageRecords[%{#innserStat.index}].heureFin"/>
    </div>
    <div class="gu desk-w10">
        <s:select name="plageRecords[%{#innserStat.index}].heureFin"
                  cssClass="rev-side-m1 rev-width" list="endHourList"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "the form isn't submitting properly." - any more specific info?

Comment: Yes of course, the action is never reached and is returning `input`, even if the validation isn't done.

Comment: Did you check what the post body looks like? It would be best to post a [mcve].

Comment: Oh thanks you put me on the right direction, I was sure that the issue was coming from the jsp but the problem was the type of the property `heureDebut` and `heureFin` in my record.

Comment: Thanks it's solved :)

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong expression in the if tag:

```
<s:if test="%{#plage.jour == #stat.index}">
```

it should be

```
<s:if test="%{#plage.jour == #jour}">
```

if expression is not evaluated or evaluated to `false` then select tag will never be added to the form, and the formdata will never be submitted.